# How to implement video that support in ie8

Tags: html, css

Hi friends i used video tag in html, ie8 its not working. how to implement video in ie8.

```
        <video width="300" height="200" controls>
        <source src="pencuin.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
```

Can any one suggest me solution, thanks.

Comment: Please check this tutorial: [Video For Everybody (HTML5 Video with Flash Fallback)](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/video-for-everybody-html5-video-with-flash-fallback/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [SWFObject: Javascript Flash Player](http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/).

Try this example: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-play-video-using-an-open-source-player--net-4144

Answer (score 2):

IE8 does not support the video tag. In this case, IE8 displays instead the contents of the video tag, which is hidden in browsers which support the tag.

To support IE8, find a video player using Flash and place the `<object>` tags inside the `<video>` and follow the instructions for that video player to choose the right video for it to play. Newer browsers will use the video tag and will not require Flash, but users of older browsers must use Flash.

Comment: how about using shiv or modernizer plugins that support ie8, is that possible.

Comment: @manojistack You don't need to use something like modernizer to do this, as the elements that are children of the `<video>` tag are displayed when the video tag is not supported (as in the case of IE8). Find a library for Flash video or use something like [VideoJS](http://www.videojs.com/).